# Haskell: List append operation

Tags: list, haskell

I'm looking at [99 problems solved in Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/99_questions/Solutions/26). I'm trying to understand few basics here.

```
    combinations :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
    combinations _ [] = [[]]
    combinations 0 _  = [[]]
    combinations k (x:xs) = x_start ++ others
    where x_start = [ x : rest | rest <- combinations (k-1) xs ]
          others  = if k <= length xs then combinations k xs else []
```

consider, `combinations 1 [3, 4]`

pattern matches with the `combinations k (x:xs)`. We will start with computing x_start which will be `x_start = [3 : combinations 0 [4]]`

`combinations 0 [4]` will pattern match with `combinations 0 [4]` and "return" `[[]]` (a list of 1 elem empty list)

we now see `x_start = [3 : combinations 0 [4]] ===> x_start = [3 : [[]]]`. Is this correct? if so what would x_start be at this point, going by list prepend operator `:`, will `x_start = [[3, []]]` which is not same as [[3]]?

when I try to print this in ghci, it complains

```
No instance for (Num [t0]) arising from a use of ‘it’
In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Comment: could you please show what exactly are you trying to print? what is `it`?

Comment: Hi I'm trying to print`*Main> [3 : [[]]]

<interactive>:17:1:
    No instance for (Num [t0]) arising from a use of ‘it’
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
`

Comment: Well, I guess that problem is `[3 : [[]]]` expression could not be typed by ghci well, because first element is `Num a` and second element is list of lists, not lists of Nums. This is what compiler is trying to say to you

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, so its just a problem with GHCI not able to figure out the type of the expression? Is the rest of my understanding correct, other than the print issue? what would x_start be [[3]] or [[3, []]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We will start with computing x_start which will be x_start = [3 : combinations 0 [4]]

This is not true, because `x_start` and `others` are of type `[[a1]]`. So it's more likely that `x_start = [3] : rest`, where `rest` is coming (since list comprehension here is just a syntax sugar with List Monad `<-` usage) from the `combinations 0 [4]`. Because of definition `combinations 0 [4]` is a `[[]]`, thus there is only one value came from it - `[]`. Finally,  `[3] : []` is `[[3]]`.

As it mentioned in the comments, `[3 : [[]]]` expression could not be typed by ghci well, because first element is Num a and second element is list of lists, not lists of `Num`s. This is what compiler is trying to say.

Comment: Hi Wouldn't *Main> [[3] : (combinations 0 [4]) ] be [[[3],[]]]
And if we [[[3],[]]]  ++ combinations 1 [4] be  `[[3],[],[4]]` which is NOT [[3], [4]]....

Comment: I'm just trying to understand how `combinations 1 [3,4]` is giving `[[3],[4]]` instead of `[[3], [], [4], []]` how is the empty list avoided and not inserted in the final list constructed.